# Can one concatenate functions in OCaml?

Tags: function, ocaml

For the purposes of the example, let's assume that everything is an integer. Also, I am aware that the compiler will be mad that the functions don't account for every case.

Let's say I have these two functions:

```
let f1 = function 
    | a -> b;;

let f2 = function
    | c -> d;;
```

Is there any way I can make a function that does this:

```
    | a -> b;;
    | c -> d;;
```

by putting together f1 and f2 (in a style similar to concatenating 2 lists) without explicitly hardcoding them together?

Comment: I tried to answer, but I guess the question isn't specific enough.  I end up with all questions and no answer.  First question: is this a homework assignment?  Second: what types are involved?  What are `a` and `c`?  If I assume they're constants of the same type, both of these functions are partial, i.e., prone to raising exceptions.  This might be a hint.

Comment: 1. Yes
2. Just assume they're all integers.

Comment: @AlexChiou: is this a homework question? It doesn't like so to me (a bit too weird) so I would answer this more explicitly, but I don't want to undo the great care that Jeffrey has taken in being only hinting.

Answer (score 2):

```
let concat_funs f1 f2 x =
  try f1 x
  with Match_failure _ -> f2 x
```

and it is associative, but not commutative.

Answer (score 0):

For homework, I think the rule is that you should show some code you tried and say what seems to be going wrong.  Otherwise it's hard to comment without just solving the problem.

However, I think the fact that both `f1` and `f2` are partial might be a pretty big hint, assuming I understand what you're looking for (a higher-order function that can do this for any two functions similar to `f1` and `f2`).